# Android M - Camera permission denied returns PERMISSION_GRANTED

Tags: android, android-camera, android-6.0-marshmallow

I'm testing denial of permission to an application and I'm seeing that when asking for the state of the permission it returns granted instead of denied.

[image]

I'm checking state of permissions according to Google's Guide:

```
    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(), Manifest.permission.CAMERA)
            != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

        // Should we show an explanation?
        if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(getActivity(),
                Manifest.permission.CAMERA)) {

            // Show an expanation to the user *asynchronously* -- don't block
            // this thread waiting for the user's response! After the user
            // sees the explanation, try again to request the permission.

        } else {

            // No explanation needed, we can request the permission.

            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(getActivity(),
                    new String[]{Manifest.permission.CAMERA},
                    PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_TAKE_PHOTO);

            // MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_CONTACTS is an
            // app-defined int constant. The callback method gets the
            // result of the request.
        }
    }
```

Here is what it actually returns in the first if:

[image]

State "0" means PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED

This is generating a `java.lang.RuntimeException: Fail to connect to camera service` error.

```
DEVICE IS A NEXUS 5X
```

Best regards.

Comment: What's your targetSdkVersion?

Comment: @laalto Originally its 21 tried with 23 also, same result.

Comment: You're supposed to get `PERMISSION_GRANTED` for any `targetSdkVersion` below 23, even if the user toggled off that permission group in Settings. I suggest that you uninstall the app completely, set your `targetSdkVersion` to 23, and try it again.

Comment: @CommonsWare thanks for answering Mark. I will try that. Also as a note this event is generating the CameraView class to call Camera.open() returning an EACCESS (-13) error. I will test this and update.

Comment: is the permission declared in the androidManifest ?

Comment: @j2emanue Yes it is.

Comment: @CommonsWare That was the issue. I will post an answer quoting your comment, I will change it to your answer if you post one. Thank you for sharing your knowledge with the community Mark.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quotig @CommonsWare:

> You're supposed to get PERMISSION_GRANTED for any targetSdkVersion below 23, even if the user toggled off that permission group in Settings. I suggest that you uninstall the app completely, set your targetSdkVersion to 23, and try it again.

This was the solution.

*(This answer will be marked correct temporarily until commenter posts an answer)*