# Android M - failed to check runtime permission

Tags: android, permissions, android-manifest, android-6.0-marshmallow

I have just started working with runtime permissions on Android M. I have CAMERA, READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE and WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE declared in AndroidManifest.xml

The thing is if user go to Settings and explicitly turn off permissions as below, I cannot check if my app that has Camera or Storage permissions enabled or not

[image]

I used this snippet to check if my app has a particular permission or not:

```
public static boolean hasPermission(Context c, String permission) {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23) {
        return ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(c, permission) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Surprisingly, every check with Camera and Storage permissions returns true (granted) even I turned them off in my Settings.

My `targetSdkVersion` is 23

Is this expected behavior provided by Google? I looked around the web and still could not find any documentation say anything about handle explicitly-invoked permissions.

Comment: What is your `targetSdkVersion`?

Comment: I am targeting SDK 23

Comment: What version of Android are you testing on? Right now, you only call `checkSelfPermission()` on 23+. `ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission()` can be called on any version of Android (at least back to API Level 4), so I would remove the `if` check. Your screenshot looks like it is an API Level 23 device, in which case, if your `targetSdkVersion` is 23, I cannot explain your symptoms.

Comment: I tested on my device which runs on Android M, and I did put the breakpoint on my code to trace it, it ran the `ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission()` function

Comment: I am currently facing the same issue (permissions check always states granted even after the permissions were revoked), did you find a solution lately?

Answer (score 2):

Again check for permission in onRestart().

```
@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
    @Override
    protected void onRestart() {
        super.onRestart();
        checkForPermission();
    }


@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
    private void checkForPermission() {
        int permissionCheck = checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS);
        if (permissionCheck == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Granted");
        } else {
            if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(MainActivity.this, Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS)) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Contacts Permission Required!!");
                createSnackbar("Contacts Permission Required!!", "Try Again");
            }
            ActivityCompat.
                    requestPermissions(MainActivity.this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS}, REQUEST_CONTACT);

        }
    }
```

Check out this link for further information:
https://github.com/sagarjogadia28/PermissionSample/

Comment: I ran my check, went to Settings to turn off the permissions and then went back to my app to run the check again. I dont think this is a valid answer

Comment: You have to check for permission again

Comment: i dont get your idea, I checked when the setiings are turned on and checked again when the setiings are turned off. In every case I met, it always returns true (permission granted)

Comment: onRestart() --> onStart() --> onResume() is called when back button is pressed from settings and our app becomes visible to the user so we need to check again whether the permission has been granted or not in onRestart() method.

Comment: Sagar is correct. Under normal circumstances, your app should ideally behave the way as described by him.

Comment: the problem is not that I did not check, the problem is that I checked but it returned true which means that he permissions were granted so I cannot run the code block that asks for permissions

Comment: Can you post your entire class?

Answer (score 1):

You have to change the targetSDKVersion because

> You're supposed to get PERMISSION_GRANTED for any targetSdkVersion below 23, even if the user toggled off that permission group in Settings. I suggest that you uninstall the app completely, set your targetSdkVersion to 23, and try it again.

you can check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34052881/android-m-camera-permission-denied-returns-permission-granted)

Answer (score 0):

You need to do different things.

First, ask for permission what you are trying to perform. Example camera:

```
//This is a class variable
private final static int MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_CAMERA = 1;

...

// before use camera:
// check permissions for CAMERA
if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(ActivityName.this,
        Manifest.permission.CAMERA)
        != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

    //request permission
    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(ActivityName.this,
            new String[]{Manifest.permission.CAMERA},
            MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_CAMERA);

} else {
    //permissions granted, do wahtever with camera
    functionToHandleCamera();
}
```

Then you need to handle the user response: allow or deny. So Override onRequestPermissionsResult method

```
@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode,
                                       String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
    switch (requestCode) {
        case MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_CAMERA: {
            // If request is cancelled, the result arrays are empty.
            if (grantResults.length > 0
                    && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                //permissions granted, do wahtever with camera
                functionToHandleCamera();

            } else {
                // permission denied
                Toast msg = Toast.makeText(this, "PERMISSIONS NEEDED", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                msg.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
                msg.show();
            }
            return;
        }

    }
}
```

> More info:
>   https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html

**EDIT**: if you only want to check if the permission is granted or not, you onlu need the first part of the code I've wrote.

Comment: yes, i get the idea, i first need to check if my permission is granted or not, then if not i will ask for it. Unfortunately, as I stated in my question, the result returned is always true (granted) so my code will not run to the asking permission part