# How to ask runtime permissions for Camera in Android , Runtime storage permissions

Tags: android, android-camera, barcode, android-6.0-marshmallow, runtime-permissions

I am doing an application to scan barcodes on a button click and it was working fine up to Lollipop versions. When I came to Marshmallow it stopped working. This is the error:

> camerabase an error occurred while connecting to camera 0

It forces me to turn on permission by:

Settings --> application --> my app --> camera.

My question is how to allow camera permission to my app automatically in Marshmallow or by asking the user to turn on camera at runtime. A screen shot:

[image]

Comment: https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android M - failed to check runtime permission](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38121104/android-m-failed-to-check-runtime-permission)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android marshmallow request permission?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33666071/android-marshmallow-request-permission)

Comment: Here you can find a useful method to ask runtime permissions in Android
https://handyopinion.com/ask-runtime-permission-in-kotlin-android/

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Below I have written a code for granting a runtime permissions for Camera, There is an Array of String in which you can give multiple requests granting as which is needed at runtime.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private static final int PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE = 200;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        if (checkPermission()) {
        //main logic or main code

       // . write your main code to execute, It will execute if the permission is already given.

        } else {
            requestPermission();
        }
    }

    private boolean checkPermission() {
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.CAMERA)
                != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            // Permission is not granted
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    private void requestPermission() {

        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                new String[]{Manifest.permission.CAMERA},
                PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE);
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
        switch (requestCode) {
            case PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE:
                if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Permission Granted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    // main logic
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Permission Denied", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
                        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.CAMERA)
                                != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                            showMessageOKCancel("You need to allow access permissions",
                                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                        @Override
                                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
                                                requestPermission();
                                            }
                                        }
                                    });
                        }
                    }
                }
                break;
        }
    }

    private void showMessageOKCancel(String message, DialogInterface.OnClickListener okListener) {
        new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this)
                .setMessage(message)
                .setPositiveButton("OK", okListener)
                .setNegativeButton("Cancel", null)
                .create()
                .show();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 13):

*This is the complete code to implement multiple or single runtime permissions*

**Step 1**

> Add permission in `manifest` for camera and also other required 
>   permissions

like

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

**Step 2**

declare this variable

```
  public static final int REQUEST_ID_MULTIPLE_PERMISSIONS= 7;
```

and Call this method `checkAndroidVersion()` in `oncreate()`

```
private void checkAndroidVersion() {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            checkAndRequestPermissions();

        } else {
            // code for lollipop and pre-lollipop devices
        }

    }


private boolean checkAndRequestPermissions() {
        int camera = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(),
                Manifest.permission.CAMERA);
        int wtite = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(), Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
        int read = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(), Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
        List<String> listPermissionsNeeded = new ArrayList<>();
        if (wtite != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            listPermissionsNeeded.add(Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
        }
        if (camera != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            listPermissionsNeeded.add(Manifest.permission.CAMERA);
        }
        if (read != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            listPermissionsNeeded.add(Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
        }
        if (!listPermissionsNeeded.isEmpty()) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(getActivity(), listPermissionsNeeded.toArray(new String[listPermissionsNeeded.size()]), REQUEST_ID_MULTIPLE_PERMISSIONS);
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }


@Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode,
                                           String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
        Log.d("in fragment on request", "Permission callback called-------");
        switch (requestCode) {
            case REQUEST_ID_MULTIPLE_PERMISSIONS: {

                Map<String, Integer> perms = new HashMap<>();
                // Initialize the map with both permissions
                perms.put(Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED);
                perms.put(Manifest.permission.CAMERA, PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED);
                perms.put(Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED);
                // Fill with actual results from user
                if (grantResults.length > 0) {
                    for (int i = 0; i < permissions.length; i++)
                        perms.put(permissions[i], grantResults[i]);
                    // Check for both permissions
                    if (perms.get(Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
                            && perms.get(Manifest.permission.CAMERA) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && perms.get(Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                        Log.d("in fragment on request", "CAMERA & WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission granted");
                        // process the normal flow
                        //else any one or both the permissions are not granted
                    } else {
                        Log.d("in fragment on request", "Some permissions are not granted ask again ");
                        //permission is denied (this is the first time, when "never ask again" is not checked) so ask again explaining the usage of permission
//                        // shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale will return true
                        //show the dialog or snackbar saying its necessary and try again otherwise proceed with setup.
                        if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(getActivity(), Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) || ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(getActivity(), Manifest.permission.CAMERA) || ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(getActivity(), Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)) {
                            showDialogOK("Camera and Storage Permission required for this app",
                                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                        @Override
                                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                            switch (which) {
                                                case DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE:
                                                    checkAndRequestPermissions();
                                                    break;
                                                case DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEGATIVE:
                                                    // proceed with logic by disabling the related features or quit the app.
                                                    break;
                                            }
                                        }
                                    });
                        }
                        //permission is denied (and never ask again is  checked)
                        //shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale will return false
                        else {
                            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Go to settings and enable permissions", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                                    .show();
                            //                            //proceed with logic by disabling the related features or quit the app.
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

    }

    private void showDialogOK(String message, DialogInterface.OnClickListener okListener) {
        new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity())
                .setMessage(message)
                .setPositiveButton("OK", okListener)
                .setNegativeButton("Cancel", okListener)
                .create()
                .show();
    }
```

Comment: worked great for me . thanks!
samsung S6, android 7.0

Comment: still works, android 10;

Comment: Excuse me, where did you write those code in? which file?

Comment: @ChanrithisakPHOK you can write in activity class or fragment?

Answer (score 9):

```
    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getContext(),
            Manifest.permission.CAMERA) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

        if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale((Activity)
                getContext(), Manifest.permission.CAMERA)) {


        } else {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions((Activity) getContext(), 
                    new String[]{Manifest.permission.CAMERA},
                    MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_CAMERA);
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 6):

[This sample Profile project demonstrates how to get **Read Storage and Camera Permission** in Android and also how to handle when the user selects **DENY & DON'T ASK AGAIN**.](https://github.com/RasoolMohamed27/Read-Storage-and-Camera-Permission)

[image]

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

    registerStoragePermission()
    registerGalleryLauncher()

    registerCameraPermission()
    registerCameraLauncher()
}

private fun registerCameraPermission() {
    requestCameraPermissionLauncher =
        registerForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.RequestPermission()) { granted ->
            if (granted) {
                Log.d(TAG, "registerCameraPermission - Camera Permission Granted")
                openCamera()
            } else {
                Log.d(TAG, "registerCameraPermission - Camera Permission NOT Granted")
                requestCameraPermission()
            }
        }
}

private fun registerStoragePermission() {
    requestStoragePermissionLauncher =
        registerForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.RequestPermission()) { granted ->
            if (granted) {
                Log.d(TAG, "registerStoragePermission - Storage Permission Granted")
                viewGallery()
            } else {
                Log.d(TAG, "registerStoragePermission - Storage Permission NOT Granted")
                requestStoragePermission()
            }
        }
}

private fun registerCameraLauncher() {
    cameraLauncher =
        registerForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult()) { result ->
            if (result.resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                val data: Intent? = result.data
                if (data == null) {
                    return@registerForActivityResult
                }
                val extras = data.extras
                imageBitmap = extras!!["data"] as Bitmap
                file = FileUtils.createFile(requireContext(),
                    getString(R.string.app_name),
                    "my_profile_image.png"
                )
                //FileUtils.saveBitmap(imageBitmap, file);
                val imageLocalPath = FileUtils.saveImageToInternalStorage(file, imageBitmap)

                SharedPreferencesUtils.setProfilePath(requireActivity(), imageLocalPath)
                profileFragmentBinding.imageViewCircleNoStroke.setImageBitmap(imageBitmap)
                profileFragmentBinding.imageViewCircleNoStroke.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP)
            }
        }
}

private fun registerGalleryLauncher() {
    galleryLauncher =
        registerForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult()) { result ->
            if (result.resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                val data: Intent? = result.data
                if (data == null) {
                    return@registerForActivityResult
                }
                val uri = data.data
                var imageLocalPath = File(FileUtils.getPathReal(requireActivity(), uri!!))

                file = imageLocalPath.absoluteFile

                SharedPreferencesUtils.setProfilePath(requireActivity(), imageLocalPath.absolutePath)
                Glide.with(requireActivity()).load(uri)
                    .into(profileFragmentBinding.imageViewCircleNoStroke)
                profileFragmentBinding.imageViewCircleNoStroke.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP)
            }
        }
}

private fun showImageUploadOptions() {
    val mDialog = activity.let { Dialog(it!!) }
    mDialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE)
    mDialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog_profile_image_option)
    mDialog.window!!.setBackgroundDrawable(ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT))
    //val mAlertMessageTv = mDialog.findViewById<View>(R.id.id_alert_tv) as TextView
    //mAlertMessageTv.text = message
    galleryLl = mDialog.findViewById<View>(R.id.id_gallery_ll) as LinearLayout
    cameraLl = mDialog.findViewById<View>(R.id.id_camera_ll) as LinearLayout
    removePhotoLl = mDialog.findViewById<View>(R.id.id_remove_photo_ll) as LinearLayout

    galleryLl.setOnClickListener {
        CallStoragePermission()
        mDialog.dismiss()
    }

    cameraLl.setOnClickListener {
        CallCameraPermission()
        mDialog.dismiss()
    }

    removePhotoLl.setOnClickListener {
        CallRemovePhoto()
        mDialog.dismiss()
    }

    mDialog.setCancelable(true)
    mDialog.show()
    val metrics = resources.displayMetrics
    val width = metrics.widthPixels
    val height = metrics.heightPixels
    mDialog.window!!.setLayout(
        width,
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
    )

}

fun CallStoragePermission() {

    if (!Status_checkReadExternalStoragePermission()) {
        requestStoragePermissionLauncher.launch(Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
    } else {
        viewGallery()
    }
}

private fun Status_checkReadExternalStoragePermission(): Boolean {
    val permissionState = ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(
        requireActivity(),
        Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
    )
    return permissionState == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
}

private fun requestCameraPermission() {

    when {
        ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(
            requireContext(),
            Manifest.permission.CAMERA
        ) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED -> {

            Log.d(TAG, "requestCameraPermission - Camera Permission Granted")
            openCamera()

            // The permission is granted
            // you can go with the flow that requires permission here
        }
        shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(Manifest.permission.CAMERA) -> {
            // This case means user previously denied the permission
            // So here we can display an explanation to the user
            // That why exactly we need this permission
            Log.d(TAG, "requestCameraPermission - Camera Permission NOT Granted")
            showPermissionAlert(
                getString(R.string.camera_permission),
                getString(R.string.camera_permission_denied),
                getString(R.string.ok_caps),
                getString(R.string.cancel_caps)
            ) { requestCameraPermissionLauncher.launch(Manifest.permission.CAMERA) }
        }
        else -> {
            // Everything is fine you can simply request the permission

            showPermissionAlert(
                getString(R.string.camera_permission),
                getString(R.string.camera_permission_denied),
                getString(R.string.settings_caps),
                getString(R.string.cancel_caps)
            ) {
                val intent = Intent()
                intent.action = Settings.ACTION_APPLICATION_DETAILS_SETTINGS
                val uri = Uri.fromParts(
                    "package",
                    BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID, null
                )
                intent.data = uri
                intent.flags = Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK
                startActivity(intent)
            }

        }
    }
}


private fun requestStoragePermission() {

    when {
        ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(
            requireContext(),
            Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
        ) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED -> {

            Log.d(TAG, "requestStoragePermission - Storage Permission Granted")
            viewGallery()

            // The permission is granted
            // you can go with the flow that requires permission here
        }
        shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) -> {
            // This case means user previously denied the permission
            // So here we can display an explanation to the user
            // That why exactly we need this permission
            Log.d(TAG, "requestStoragePermission - Storage Permission NOT Granted")
            showPermissionAlert(
                getString(R.string.read_storage_permission_required),
                getString(R.string.storage_permission_denied),
                getString(R.string.ok_caps),
                getString(R.string.cancel_caps)
            ) { requestStoragePermissionLauncher.launch(Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) }
        }
        else -> {
            // Everything is fine you can simply request the permission

            showPermissionAlert(
                getString(R.string.read_storage_permission_required),
                getString(R.string.storage_permission_denied),
                getString(R.string.settings_caps),
                getString(R.string.cancel_caps)
            ) {
                val intent = Intent()
                intent.action = Settings.ACTION_APPLICATION_DETAILS_SETTINGS
                val uri = Uri.fromParts(
                    "package",
                    BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID, null
                )
                intent.data = uri
                intent.flags = Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK
                startActivity(intent)
            }

        }
    }
}

private fun showPermissionAlert(
    title: String,
    message: String,
    ok: String,
    cancel: String,
    function: () -> Unit
) {
    val mDialog = requireActivity().let { Dialog(it) }
    mDialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE)
    mDialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog_permission_alert)
    mDialog.window!!.setBackgroundDrawable(ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT))

    val mTitleTv = mDialog.findViewById<View>(R.id.id_title_tv) as AppCompatTextView
    mTitleTv.text = title

    val mMessageTv = mDialog.findViewById<View>(R.id.id_message_tv) as AppCompatTextView
    mMessageTv.text = message

    val mNoBtn = mDialog.findViewById<View>(R.id.no_btn) as AppCompatTextView
    mNoBtn.text = cancel

    val mYesBtn = mDialog.findViewById<View>(R.id.yes_btn) as AppCompatTextView
    mYesBtn.text = ok

    mYesBtn.setOnClickListener {
        function.invoke()
        mDialog.dismiss()
    }

    mNoBtn.setOnClickListener { mDialog.dismiss() }

    mDialog.setCancelable(true)
    mDialog.show()
    val metrics = resources.displayMetrics
    val width = metrics.widthPixels
    val height = metrics.heightPixels
    mDialog.window!!.setLayout(
        width,
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
    )
}

fun viewGallery() {
    val intentDocument = Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT)
    intentDocument.type = "image/*"
    intentDocument.putExtra(
        Constants.REQUEST_CODE,
        Constants.REQUEST_PHOTO_FROM_GALLERY
    )
    galleryLauncher.launch(intentDocument)
}

fun openCamera() {
    val takePictureIntent = Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE)
    takePictureIntent.putExtra(
        Constants.REQUEST_CODE,
        Constants.REQUEST_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_CODE_CAMERA
    )
    cameraLauncher.launch(takePictureIntent)
}

fun CallCameraPermission() {
    if (!Status_checkCameraPermission()) {
        requestCameraPermissionLauncher.launch(Manifest.permission.CAMERA)
    } else {
        openCamera()
    }
}

private fun Status_checkCameraPermission(): Boolean {
    val camera = ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(
        requireActivity(),
        Manifest.permission.CAMERA
    )

    return camera == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
}
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/29505706)

Comment: @Tomerikoo - Thank you, Added essential parts of code...

Answer (score 5):

[**RxPermission**](https://github.com/tbruyelle/RxPermissions) is best library for asking permissions from user.

For camera permission the workaround is like this.

1) First add these permissions (or one you need) in your `manifest.xml`.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
```

2) Then ask run time permission from user in your activity.

```
RxPermissions rxPermissions = new RxPermissions(this);
rxPermissions
.request(Manifest.permission.CAMERA) // ask single or multiple permission once
.subscribe(granted -> {
    if (granted) {
       // All requested permissions are granted
    } else {
       // At least one permission is denied
    }
});
```

add this library in your `build.gradle`

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        ...
        maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'com.github.tbruyelle:rxpermissions:0.10.1'
    implementation 'com.jakewharton.rxbinding2:rxbinding:2.1.1'
}
```

**Isn't this easy?**

Answer (score 4):

Manifest.xml

```xml
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
```

Call it somewhere in your activity:

```
handlePermissions(new String[]{
    Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
    Manifest.permission.CAMERA
});
```

Also in your activity:

```
    private void handlePermissions(String[] permissions) {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            ArrayList<String> notGrantedPerms = new ArrayList<>();
            for (String p : permissions) {
                if (this.checkSelfPermission(p) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
                    notGrantedPerms.add(p);
            }
            permissions = notGrantedPerms.toArray(new String[0]);
            if (permissions != null && permissions.length > 0)
                this.requestPermissions(permissions, 701);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        if (requestCode == 701) {
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
                for (String p : permissions) {
                    String msg = "";
                    if (this.checkSelfPermission(p) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
                        msg = "Permission Granted for " + p;
                    else
                        msg = "Permission not Granted for " + p;
                    Toast.makeText(this, msg, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

```
void AutoRequestAllPermissions(){
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.M){return;}
        PackageInfo info = null;
        try {
            info = getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(getApplicationContext().getPackageName(), PackageManager.GET_PERMISSIONS);
        } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        if(info==null){return;}
        String[] permissions = info.requestedPermissions;
        boolean remained = false;
        for (String permission : permissions) {
            if (checkSelfPermission(permission) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                remained = true;
            }
        }
        if(remained) {
            requestPermissions(permissions, 0);
        }
    }
```

this code-

1. automatically read all permissions from manifest
2. then check if any permission is not granted
3. then request that remaining permissions

Comment: best and easy solution!

Answer (score 1):

```
Try my code - 
  <!-- add permissions to the manifest file -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />


MainActivity - 
  
package com.company0ne.multiplepermissionkotlin

import android.Manifest
import android.content.pm.PackageManager
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import androidx.activity.result.ActivityResultLauncher
import androidx.activity.result.contract.ActivityResultContracts
import androidx.core.content.ContextCompat

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var permissionLauncher: ActivityResultLauncher<Array<String>>
private var isCameraPermissionGranted = false


    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        //Request Multiple Permissions
        permissionLauncher =
            registerForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.RequestMultiplePermissions()) { permissions ->


                isCameraPermissionGranted =
                    permissions[Manifest.permission.CAMERA] ?: isCameraPermissionGranted

            }
        requestPermission()
    }

    private fun requestPermission() {

        //read camera permission from Manifest file
        isCameraPermissionGranted = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(
            this,
            Manifest.permission.CAMERA
        ) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED

        //if request is not null then it will ask for permissions
        val permissionRequest: MutableList<String> = ArrayList()


        if (!isCameraPermissionGranted) {

            permissionRequest.add(Manifest.permission.CAMERA)
        }
    if (permissionRequest.isNotEmpty()) {

        permissionLauncher.launch(permissionRequest.toTypedArray())
    }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This might help:

```
if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, Manifest.permission.CAMERA) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
{
    if(ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale((Activity) context, Manifest.permission.CAMERA))
    {
        AlertDialog.Builder alertBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
        alertBuilder.setCancelable(true);
        alertBuilder.setTitle("Permission necessary");
        alertBuilder.setMessage("CAMERA is necessary");
        alertBuilder.setPositiveButton(android.R.string.yes, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN)
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions((Activity) context, 
                new String[]{Manifest.permission.CAMERA}, MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUESTS);
            }
        });
        AlertDialog alert = alertBuilder.create();
        alert.show();
    } else {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions((Activity) context, new String[]{Manifest.permission.CAMERA}, MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUESTS);
    }
    return false;
} else {
    return true;
}
```

Where `MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUESTS` is your final value of the request code.

It works just fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

After having it defined in your manifest file, a friendlier alternative to the native solution would be using Aaper: https://github.com/LikeTheSalad/aaper like so:

```
@EnsurePermissions(permissions = [Manifest.permission.CAMERA])
private fun takePhoto() {
    // Your code that needs the camera permission granted.
}
```

Disclaimer, I'm the creator of Aaper.

Answer (score 0):

Android team has provided a new way in requesting permissions using registerForActivityResult,

```
        <uses-permission
        android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

Define an object to request permissions, and receive the result in the

```
    callback
      private val requestPermissionsLauncher =
        registerForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.RequestMultiplePermissions()) { permissions ->
            if (permissions.all { it.value }) {
                Toast.makeText(
                    this,
                    "You have obtained the required permissions",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG
                ).show()
            } else Toast.makeText(
                this,
                "You have not accepted all the permissions",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG
            ).show()
        }
```

To ask for the permissions, do the following, you can add wherever you think is better:

```
 requestPermissionsLauncher.launch(
                arrayOf(
                    Manifest.permission.CAMERA,
                    Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
                )
            )
```