# Request permissions and onRequestPermissionResult in "androidx.fragment.app.Fragment"

Tags: android, android-fragments, androidx

I'm a beginner in android, and would appreciate any help.
Basically in `androidx.fragment.app.Fragment` after calling `requestPermissions()` , `onRequestPermissionsResult()` is never called.

I read on another question ([onRequestPermissionsResult not being called in fragment if defined in both fragment and activity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35989288/onrequestpermissionsresult-not-being-called-in-fragment-if-defined-in-both-fragm)) that `ActivityCompat.requestPermissions` would result in activity's `onRequestPermissionsResult` method being called. and simple `requestPermissions` would call `onRequestPermissionsResult` in same fragment. I've tried both ways but every time activity's method is being called i think maybe because this is not a v4 support fragment but a `androidx.fragment.app.Fragment`.

I tried overriding `onRequestPermissionsResult` in activity and called super's method but still fragment's method is not being called.

```java
private final String[] REQUIRED_PERMISSIONS = new String[]{"android.permission.CAMERA", "android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"};
private int REQUEST_CODE_PERMISSIONS = 10;

@Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
        setupTimeOut();

        if (allPermissionsGranted()) {
            // Do stuff that requires permission
        } else {
            requestPermissions(REQUIRED_PERMISSIONS, REQUEST_CODE_PERMISSIONS);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE_PERMISSIONS) {
            if (allPermissionsGranted()) {
                // Do stuff that requires permission
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getViewContext(), "Permissions not granted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    }

    private boolean allPermissionsGranted() {
        //check if req permissions have been granted
        for (String permission : REQUIRED_PERMISSIONS) {
            if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getViewContext(), permission) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
```

what i want is to get the permissions result callback in same fragment.
In case this is relevant, permissions are for camera and write external storage and fragment is a simple photo capture fragment.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42275906/how-to-ask-runtime-permissions-for-camera/52201117#52201117

Comment: @Quicklearner 'ActivityCompat.requestPermissions' callback method is supposed to be in base activity of fragment (which is what's used in linked answer). but i need to get call back in the same fragment.

Comment: you can use it in your child fragment anywhere you want to use

Comment: Sample code i shared is inside a child Fragment. But still `onRequestPermissionsResult` is not being called. Even though the Parent activity's `onRequestPermissionsResult` is !    maybe i'm missing something here ?!!