# Flashlight for Android on Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, flashlight

You need to turn on the LED on your phone. I wrote a simple application. The LED should turn on when the app starts. The code matches the solutions on Stackoverflow
Application code:

```
package com.example.flash

import android.hardware.Camera
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

 override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
     setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
     var cam = Camera.open()
     var p = cam.parameters
     p.flashMode = Camera.Parameters.FLASH_MODE_TORCH
     cam.parameters = p
     cam.startPreview()
 }
}
```

AndroidManifest.xml:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.kgskassa">
       <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
       <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
       <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FLASHLIGHT"/>
       <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
       <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus"/>
```

Access to the camera on the phone is allowed.
Does not work. Ideas?

Comment: You say it "Does not work." - what happens?

Comment: you need to add camera runtime persmissions as well

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42275906/how-to-ask-runtime-permissions-for-camera/52201117#52201117

Comment: when permssion is granted by user then use your code to turn on LEF

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
package com.example.flash

import android.content.Context
import android.hardware.camera2.CameraAccessException
import android.hardware.camera2.CameraManager
import android.os.Bundle
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    var flashLightStatus: Boolean = false

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        openFlashLight()
    }

    private fun openFlashLight() {
        val cameraManager = getSystemService(Context.CAMERA_SERVICE) as CameraManager
        val cameraId = cameraManager.cameraIdList[0]
        if (!flashLightStatus) {
            try {
                cameraManager.setTorchMode(cameraId, true)
                flashLightStatus = true

            } catch (e: CameraAccessException) {
            }
        } else {
            try {
                cameraManager.setTorchMode(cameraId, false)
                flashLightStatus = false
            } catch (e: CameraAccessException) {
            }
        }

    }
}
```