# import library who have Permissions Requirements android

Tags: java, android, import, android-permissions, lib

I developed library which contains some activities and services like open camera and audio. In manifest at library have some `uses-permission`.

Can I import this lib without declaring again in the app all the permissions that need and define in the library?

And does library is sdk in other word?

Comment: yes it automatically included in app.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42275906/how-to-ask-runtime-permissions-for-camera-in-android-runtime-storage-permissio/52201117#52201117