# Why does my app keep crashing when launching the camera intent in a new activity?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-camera

I'm trying to launch the camera in a new activity but whenever I press the button to open the camera, my app keeps crashing. If I create a separate app to launch the camera and take a picture, it works fine. I'm clueless as to what I am doing wrong. Any advice is appreciated.

Activity for launching camera and taking a picture.

```
package com.gadget.gadgetboxv3

import android.app.Activity
import android.content.Intent
import android.graphics.Bitmap
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.provider.MediaStore
import android.widget.Button
import android.widget.ImageView
import android.widget.Toast

private const val REQUEST_CODE = 42
class CaptureImage : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_capture_image)

        val button = findViewById<Button>(R.id.btnTakePicture)
        button.setOnClickListener()
        {
            val takePictureIntent = Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE)

            if(takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(this.packageManager)!=null)
            {
                startActivity(takePictureIntent)
            }
            else
            {
                Toast.makeText(applicationContext, "Unable To Open Camera", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }
        }

    }

    override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?)
    {
        val view = findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.imageView)
        if(requestCode == REQUEST_CODE && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK)
        {
            val takenImage = data?.extras?.get("data") as Bitmap
            view.setImageBitmap(takenImage)
        }
        else
        {
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
        }
    }
}
```

Layout file for CaptureImage

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnTakePicture"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:text="Take Picture"

        />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="600dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        />


</LinearLayout>
```

Manifest for the entire app

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.gadget.gadgetboxv3">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.GadgetBoxV3">
        <activity
            android:name=".CaptureImage"
            android:exported="false"
            android:label="CaptureImage"
            android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.GadgetBoxV3" />
        <activity
            android:name=".DisplayImage"
            android:exported="false"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_display_image"
            android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.GadgetBoxV3" />
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Function I am using to open the CaptureImage activity

```
        //Function call to navigate to the capture image screen activity
        capture_image.setOnClickListener {
            //Creating an intent to navigate to the other screen
            val intent: Intent = Intent(this, CaptureImage::class.java)
            //Navigating to the other screen on function call
            startActivity(intent)
        }
```

Logcat

```
2022-03-21 03:22:20.577 742-742/? E/Zygote: isWhitelistProcess - Process is Whitelisted
2022-03-21 03:22:20.578 742-742/? E/Zygote: accessInfo : 1
2022-03-21 03:22:20.618 742-742/? E/get.gadgetboxv: Unknown bits set in runtime_flags: 0x8000
2022-03-21 03:22:21.182 742-742/com.gadget.gadgetboxv3 E/OpenCV/StaticHelper: OpenCV error: Cannot load info library for OpenCV
2022-03-21 03:22:21.202 742-742/com.gadget.gadgetboxv3 E/OpenCV/StaticHelper: OpenCV error: Cannot load info library for OpenCV
2022-03-21 03:22:40.800 742-742/com.gadget.gadgetboxv3 E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.gadget.gadgetboxv3, PID: 742
    java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: starting Intent { act=android.media.action.IMAGE_CAPTURE cmp=com.sec.android.app.camera/.Camera } from ProcessRecord{974fb19 742:com.gadget.gadgetboxv3/u0a269} (pid=742, uid=10269) with revoked permission android.permission.CAMERA
        at android.os.Parcel.createException(Parcel.java:2088)
        at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:2056)
        at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:2004)
        at android.app.IActivityTaskManager$Stub$Proxy.startActivity(IActivityTaskManager.java:4454)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1716)
        at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:5258)
        at androidx.activity.ComponentActivity.startActivityForResult(ComponentActivity.java:597)
        at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:5203)
        at androidx.activity.ComponentActivity.startActivityForResult(ComponentActivity.java:583)
        at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:5587)
        at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:5555)
        at com.gadget.gadgetboxv3.CaptureImage.onCreate$lambda-0(CaptureImage.kt:26)
        at com.gadget.gadgetboxv3.CaptureImage.$r8$lambda$A3JJRk2duhFHwC-ZfpOzOx8lFhs(Unknown Source:0)
        at com.gadget.gadgetboxv3.CaptureImage$$ExternalSyntheticLambda0.onClick(Unknown Source:2)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:7862)
        at android.widget.TextView.performClick(TextView.java:15004)
        at com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton.performClick(MaterialButton.java:1199)
        at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:7831)
        at android.view.View.access$3600(View.java:879)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:29359)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:883)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:237)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8167)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:496)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1100)
     Caused by: android.os.RemoteException: Remote stack trace:
        at com.android.server.wm.ActivityStackSupervisor.checkStartAnyActivityPermission(ActivityStackSupervisor.java:1447)
        at com.android.server.wm.ActivityStarter.startActivity(ActivityStarter.java:980)
        at com.android.server.wm.ActivityStarter.startActivity(ActivityStarter.java:732)
        at com.android.server.wm.ActivityStarter.startActivityMayWait(ActivityStarter.java:2074)
        at com.android.server.wm.ActivityStarter.execute(ActivityStarter.java:646)
```

Comment: show your error stacktrace from Logcat tab in Android Studio

Comment: Added the error stacktrace

Comment: It's saying I'm getting a permission denial but I included the camera permission in my manifest file.

Comment: thats not sufficient nowadays, you have to [ask for this permission](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting) in app runtime since Android 6.0

Comment: Will try implementing the permissions and post an update in the comments

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are occuring  `java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial ... with revoked permission android.permission.CAMERA` - your app don't have camera access permission

use [runtime permissions for acquire](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42275906/how-to-ask-runtime-permissions-for-camera-in-android-runtime-storage-permissio)

Answer (score 0):

Problem : In Your Code You don't check permission for accessing camera intent So that's why your App crash.

Answer :
Try to add below code:

```
private static final int MY_CAMERA_REQUEST_CODE = 100;

@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.M)

if (checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.CAMERA) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
    requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.CAMERA}, MY_CAMERA_REQUEST_CODE);
}
```

On onCreate Function and this following code:

```
@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
if (requestCode == MY_CAMERA_REQUEST_CODE) {
    if (grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "camera permission granted", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(this, "camera permission denied", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Camera permission is coming under the Dangerous permission category, hence it's mandatory to that ask permission during runtime from M onwards. Please check the below code for the reference.

`ActivityCompat.requestPermissions( activity, arrayOf(Manifest.permission.CAMERA), YOUR_REQUEST_CODE )`

This need to be called just before when you want to open the camera. After execution of this code, will show the dialog to grant/deny the permission by package manager.

`override fun onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode: Int, permissions: Array<String>, grantResults: IntArray) { when (requestCode) { YOUR_REQUEST_CODE -> {} }`

makesure you have added permission in manifest

`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />`

**You can also use external lib to show permission dialog like Dexter, PermissionsDispatcher or KPermissions, that will make you more concise..**